# R decode string from 6 bit binary to 8 bit binary

Tags: r, decode, rcpp

I am looking to write an equivalent R function based on a C++ snippet I have. See below:

Essentially, I want to decode this:

> I@`@@B@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@IGZJPCoA@@@@B@@|y}wqCLnLp@@@@@@z@SvA@@@q^I|VeUt@@@

which was converted six bits at a time to printable characters by adding 0x40 to each character as the message was built. The code below describes the process to convert the printable values back to binary. Once the strings have been converted from printable back to binary, they must be reordered using reverse endian conversion.

To:

> 0010 0100 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1001 0001 1101 1010 0010 1001 0000 0000 1110 1111 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 1111 0011 1001 1111 0111 0111 1100 0100 0011 0011 0010 1110 0011 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110 1000 0000 0100 1111 0110 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 0101 1110 0010 0111 1100 0101 1010 0101 0101 0111 0100 0000 0000

With an R equivalent of this:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
void Binary_Decode_6bit(char *in_string,unsigned char *out_string)
{
    int i,j;

    /* DECODE string from 6 bit binary to 8 bit binary */

    /* Convert each 4 word group into 3 words */
    for (i=0, j = 0; i < strlen(in_string); i += 4)
    {
        out_string[j++] = ((in_string[i] &0x3f) << 2)   | ((in_string[i+1] &0x30) >> 4);

        out_string[j++] = ((in_string[i+1] &0x0f) << 4) | ((in_string[i+2] &0x3c) >> 2);

        out_string[j++] = ((in_string[i+2] &0x03) << 6) | (in_string[i+3] &0x3f);
    }
}
/****************************************************************************
```

I am hoping to use a R (or even RCpp) function to apply to a rather large list of these messages.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to get the string to binary via the process laid out and convert that to decimal values. I only have a passing familiarity with encoding/decoded data. I am really looking direction of how to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your C++ (well C) code pretty directly from a function exported to R via Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

void Binary_Decode_6bit(char *in_string, unsigned char *out_string)
{
  int i,j;

  /* DECODE string from 6 bit binary to 8 bit binary */

  /* Convert each 4 word group into 3 words */
  for (i=0, j = 0; i < strlen(in_string); i += 4)
  {
    out_string[j++] = ((in_string[i] &0x3f) << 2)   | ((in_string[i+1] &0x30) >> 4);

    out_string[j++] = ((in_string[i+1] &0x0f) << 4) | ((in_string[i+2] &0x3c) >> 2);

    out_string[j++] = ((in_string[i+2] &0x03) << 6) | (in_string[i+3] &0x3f);
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RawVector decode(std::string input) {
  if (input.size() % 4 != 0) 
    Rcpp::stop("input size must be a multiple of 4");
  std::vector<unsigned char> tmp(input.size() * 3 / 4);
  Binary_Decode_6bit(&input[0], &tmp[0]);
  Rcpp::RawVector result(tmp.size());
  std::copy(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), result.begin());
  return result;
}

/*** R
decode("I@`@@B@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@IGZJPCoA@@@@B@@|y}wqCLnLp@@@@@@z@SvA@@@q^I|VeUt@@@@")
decode("I@`@@B@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@IGZJPCoA@@@@B@@|y}wqCLnLp@@@@@@z@SvA@@@q^I|VeUt@@@")
*/
```

Output:

```
> decode("I@`@@B@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@IGZJPCoA@@@@B@@|y}wqCLnLp@@@@@@z@SvA@@@q^I|VeUt@@@@")
 [1] 24 08 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 91 da 29 00 ef 04 00 00 00 20 00 f3 9f 77 c4 33
[36] 2e 33 00 00 00 00 00 e8 04 f6 04 00 00 c5 e2 7c 5a 55 74 00 00 00

> decode("I@`@@B@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@IGZJPCoA@@@@B@@|y}wqCLnLp@@@@@@z@SvA@@@q^I|VeUt@@@")
Error in decode("I@`@@B@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@IGZJPCoA@@@@B@@|y}wqCLnLp@@@@@@z@SvA@@@q^I|VeUt@@@") : 
  input size must be a multiple of 4
```

Note that I have added an additional, `@` at the end of the input string to get the required size. I have not compared the results in detail, but for the sample I have compared your binary representation is identical to my hex representation.

Comment: Wonderful! This is what I want to do, and a great start. The additional "@" should not cause an issue. Now I need to figure out how to use reverse endian conversion.